# Highcharts errors: "Cannot read property 'addEvent' of undefined" and more

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I'm using Highchart stock and got those errors in Chrome console although the chart seems to work fine.

```
GET https://code.highcharts.com/indicators/indicators-all.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403
log.js:24 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
summary:47 GET https://code.highcharts.com/indicators/indicators-all.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403
drag-panes.src.js:46 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEvent' of undefined
    at drag-panes.src.js:46
    at m (drag-panes.src.js:29)
    at drag-panes.src.js:32
    at drag-panes.src.js:23
    at drag-panes.src.js:12
(anonymous) @ drag-panes.src.js:12
m @ drag-panes.src.js:12
(anonymous) @ drag-panes.src.js:12
(anonymous) @ drag-panes.src.js:12
(anonymous) @ drag-panes.src.js:12
annotations-advanced.src.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEvent' of undefined
    at annotations-advanced.src.js:37
    at t (annotations-advanced.src.js:28)
    at annotations-advanced.src.js:31
    at annotations-advanced.src.js:22
    at annotations-advanced.src.js:11
(anonymous) @ annotations-advanced.src.js:11
t @ annotations-advanced.src.js:11
(anonymous) @ annotations-advanced.src.js:11
(anonymous) @ annotations-advanced.src.js:11
(anonymous) @ annotations-advanced.src.js:11
price-indicator.src.js:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEvent' of undefined
    at price-indicator.src.js:42
    at c (price-indicator.src.js:29)
    at price-indicator.src.js:32
    at price-indicator.src.js:23
    at price-indicator.src.js:12
(anonymous) @ price-indicator.src.js:32
c @ price-indicator.src.js:12
(anonymous) @ price-indicator.src.js:12
(anonymous) @ price-indicator.src.js:12
(anonymous) @ price-indicator.src.js:12
full-screen.src.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEvent' of undefined
    at full-screen.src.js:40
    at c (full-screen.src.js:29)
    at full-screen.src.js:32
    at full-screen.src.js:23
    at full-screen.src.js:12
(anonymous) @ full-screen.src.js:12
c @ full-screen.src.js:12
(anonymous) @ full-screen.src.js:12
(anonymous) @ full-screen.src.js:12
(anonymous) @ full-screen.src.js:12
stock-tools.src.js:124 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEvent' of undefined
    at stock-tools.src.js:124
    at q (stock-tools.src.js:29)
    at stock-tools.src.js:88
    at stock-tools.src.js:23
    at stock-tools.src.js:12
```

Here is my package.json regarding highcharts:

```
"highcharts": "^8.1.0",
"highcharts-react-official": "^3.0.0",
```

Here is how I create the chart in react component:

```
import HighStock from "highcharts/highstock"
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official"
import indicatorsAll from "highcharts/indicators/indicators-all"
import annotationsAdvanced from "highcharts/modules/annotations-advanced"
import priceIndicator from "highcharts/modules/price-indicator"
import fullScreen from "highcharts/modules/full-screen"
import stockTools from "highcharts/modules/stock-tools"

indicatorsAll(HighStock)
annotationsAdvanced(HighStock)
priceIndicator(HighStock)
fullScreen(HighStock)
stockTools(HighStock)

<HighchartsReact highcharts={HighStock} constructorType={"stockChart"} options={options} />
```

Comment: Hi @newman, Could you reproduce that problem in some onlince code editor? Here: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-glbkm?file=/demo.jsx everything works as it should.

Comment: @ppotaczek Thank you very much for the working demo link which helped me to track down my problem -- somehow, I got a few highcharts js files included in my index.html which are unnecessary. Once I remove them, everything works fine. Really appreciated!